# Looping between two Dates in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date, between

I'm a fresher for Excel vba and just looking to have a code to populate dates in between given dates and print it to a new column

My dates are

```
26/09/2020
1/07/2020
26/09/2020
1/05/2020
23/06/2020
15/10/2020
```

and I'm looking to have a date order like below

```
1/04/2020
1/05/2020
1/06/2020
**23/06/2020** Month break here
1/07/2020
1/08/2020
1/09/2020
**26/09/2020** month break here
1/10/2020
**15/10/2020** month break here
1/11/2020
```

so far Idea i get to find Min and Max and used this code.. can't really get any help from anywhere

```
Sub MAX_FIND()
Min_Date as date
Max_date as Date

Min_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("b7:b12"))
Range("c3") = DateAdd("m", -1, Min_date)'

Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("b7:b12"))
add_max = DateAdd("m", 1, Max_date)
Range("D3") = DateSerial(Year(add_max), Month(add_max), 1)

    End Sub
```

Really appreciate in advance.. thanks

Comment: Would help to explain the rules by which you get the second list.  Don't make us guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates your desired date order from your input.

We use the `ArrayList` (a member of the `System.Collection` object) to

- create a unique list of the dates (remove duplicates)
- Sort both ways to easily get a method of obtaining the first and last dates
- Add the first date, last date, and any intervening missing first of the month dates to the list
- Then we transfer this to a regular array, to do some special processing on the existing dates that are not the first of the month (as you show in your example):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Dts()
    Dim arrDts As Object
    Dim v, w, dt, I As Long
    Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date
    
Set arrDts = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'get unique list of dts
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    v = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With
    For Each w In v
        If Not arrDts.contains(w) Then arrDts.Add w
    Next w
    
'sort the dates

arrDts.Sort
    dtStart = DateSerial(Year(arrDts(0)), Month(arrDts(0)) - 1, 1)
arrDts.Reverse
    dtEnd = DateSerial(Year(arrDts(0)), Month(arrDts(0)) + 1, 1)
    
arrDts.Add dtStart
arrDts.Add dtEnd
arrDts.Sort

'add intervening months
dt = dtStart
Do Until dt = dtEnd
    dt = DateAdd("m", 1, dt)
    If Not arrDts.contains(dt) Then arrDts.Add dt
Loop

arrDts.Sort
v = arrDts.toarray

Dim vRes
ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(v) + 1, 1 To 1)

'add in the month breaks

For I = 0 To UBound(v)
    If Day(v(I)) <> 1 Then
        vRes(I + 1, 1) = "**" & Format(v(I), "dd-mmm-yyyy") & "** Month break here"
    Else
        vRes(I + 1, 1) = v(I)
    End If
Next I

With Range("c1").Resize(UBound(vRes))
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Note that if you do not want to have the text along with the "month breaks", there's no need to format them as text.  Simply:

```
For I = 0 To UBound(v)
    vRes(I + 1, 1) = v(I)
Next I
```

[image]

Comment: First I need to thank you for a quick reply... works like a charm and only issue I'm having with this is just the date formatting... 28/09/2020  4/01/2020
1/07/2020  5/01/2020
26/09/2020  6/01/2020
1/05/2020  23/06/2020
23/06/2020  7/01/2020
15/10/2020  8/01/2020
  9/01/2020
  26/09/2020
  28/09/2020
  10/01/2020
  15/10/2020
  11/01/2020 . format come up like mm/dd/yyyy where date start from 1st date of month

Comment: @vikramverma Interesting issue which I've not run across previously. Seems to be a complication of the `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` method when used on variant arrays containing dates.  See if edited function works OK for you.

Comment: really appreciate your help.. at first it seems giving duplicate date and if three or more dates in one moth it was playing up.. but some how I get this working with little change in your code [Dim vRes

ReDim vRes(0 To UBound(v) + 1, 1 To 1)

    If Day(v(I)) <> 1 Then
        vRes(I, 1) = Format(v(I), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
    Else
        vRes(I, 1) = v(I)
    End If
Next I
With Range("c1").Resize(UBound(v) + 1)
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With] ... thanks alot again for your help..

Comment: @vikramverma The issue had to do with an error I made in correcting the transpose problem.  The only change that needed to be made was from ` Format(v(I+1), "dd-mmm-yyyy")` to ` Format(v(I), "dd-mmm-yyyy")`.  But why even bother to format as text at all?

Comment: Thanks mate... as I mention previously I'm new for this forum, so don't really know what to do.. Just accepted

Answer (score 0):

Or another way is something like this :

```
Sub test()
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet7")

With sh1
Set Rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Min_date = Application.Min(Rng)
Max_date = Application.Max(Rng)
Max_date = Format(DateAdd("m", 2, Max_date), "mmm-yy")

    Do
    x = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Max_date), "mmm yy")
    y = Format(DateAdd("m", -2, Min_date), "mmm yy")
    If x = y Then Exit Do
    .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    "1" & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Max_date), "/mmm/yy")
    Max_date = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Max_date), "mmm yy")
    Loop

Set Rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Rng.NumberFormat = "d\/mm\/yyyy" '--> the format depends on the computer setting..., mine need to be like that, but other computer maybe can just have d/mm/yyyy
Rng.Sort Key1:=Rng.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Set strt = .Range("A1")

    Do
    If strt.Value = strt.Offset(1, 0).Value Then strt.Offset(1, 0).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Set strt = strt.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop Until strt.Value = ""

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Ron Rosenfeld for quick response.. his solution work as a charm..

I did a little tweak to get that working as per my requirements..

**final code**

```
    Sub Dts_New()
    Dim arrDts As Object
    Dim v, w, dt, I As Long
    Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date
    
Set arrDts = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'get unique list of dts
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    v = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With
    For Each w In v
        If Not arrDts.contains(w) Then arrDts.Add w
    Next w
    
'sort the dates

arrDts.Sort
    dtStart = DateSerial(Year(arrDts(0)), Month(arrDts(0)) - 1, 1)
arrDts.Reverse
    dtEnd = DateSerial(Year(arrDts(0)), Month(arrDts(0)) + 1, 1)
    
arrDts.Add dtStart
arrDts.Add dtEnd
arrDts.Sort

'add intervening months
dt = dtStart
Do Until dt = dtEnd
    dt = DateAdd("m", 1, dt)
    If Not arrDts.contains(dt) Then arrDts.Add dt
Loop

arrDts.Sort
v = arrDts.toarray

Dim vRes

ReDim vRes(0 To UBound(v) + 1, 1 To 1)

'add in the month breaks

For I = 0 To UBound(v)
    If Day(v(I)) <> 1 Then
        vRes(I, 1) = Format(v(I), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
        'Debug.Print v(I)
    Else
        vRes(I, 1) = v(I)
    'Debug.Print v(I)
    End If
    
    'Debug.Print v(I)
Next I



With Range("c1").Resize(UBound(v) + 1)
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

]

appreciate your help..

Love this community.. wish i get to know this before... :)